# k-combinations in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, combinations

What is the most efficient way to generate k-tuples with all k-combinations from a given python set? Is there an appropriate built-in function? Something tells me it should be possible with a two-line for loop.

P.S. I did conduct a search and found various entries to the topic "combinations from lists, etc in Python", but all proposed solutions seem rather 'un-python'. I am hoping for a mind-blowing, idiomatic python expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) has all of those types of functions:

```
import itertools

for combination in itertools.combinations(iterable, k):
    print(combination)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I had come up with
for a in set: for b in set: if a!=b and {a,b} not in combinations and {b,a} not in combinations: combinations.append({a,b})
but of course this solution is ridiculously inefficient for k>3. I did not know itertools, so I am all the more grateful.